# upload a particular picture instead of submitting full form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form name editdata.php. around 10 html controls(text box,file,select) using. I have a file control their picture of user is displaying and below this a file control is attached to change picture. I want that when a user browse and then change picture picture will automatically changed but form will not submit. so is this possible to upload picture without submitting the full form.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <html lang="en">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">           <!--requuired for bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />               <!--bootstrap files -->
     <script src="Bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <style>
         .error
         {
             color: red;

         }
     </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Login Form</h1> 
        <h2><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) echo $_REQUEST['msg'] ?></h2>            <!--  Successful messgaeg if chnaged password -->
    <form action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkData()"  role="">

         <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username*</label>
                <div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" value="<?php if(isset($un)) echo $un;  ?>" name="uname" onblur="setTimeout(function abc(){check_login_data('uname erruname blur', 'Username Must Be Entered')},130)" onfocus="check_login_data('uname erruname focus')" placeholder="Enter Username" />     <!-- textbox for username and checking value for cookie  -->   
                </div>
        </div>
         <span class="error" id="erruname"> <?php if (isset($errorforusrnam)) echo $errorforusrnam; ?> </span>         <!-- set a span for displaying error on emplty textbox -->

        <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password*</label>
                <div><input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_id" name="upass" value="<?php if(isset($up)) echo ($up);  ?>" placeholder="Enter Password" onblur="setTimeout(function abc(){check_login_data('password_id errpassword blur','Password Should Entered')},130)" onfocus="check_login_data('password_id errpassword focus')" />            <!-- textbox for Password and checking value for cookie  -->
                </div>
        </div>
        <span class="error" id="errpassword"> <?php if(isset($errorforpwd)) echo $errorforpwd ?> </span>         <!-- set a span for displaying error on emplty textbox -->

        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['counter']) && $_SESSION['counter']>3)           //captcha will show if user attempts more then 3
        {
        echo "<div class=form-group >";                 //div for captcha
        echo "<label for=captcha >Captcha*</label>";
                  echo "<div id=captcha_id>";
                      echo "<img id=imgCaptcha class=img-responsive src=captcha/create_image.php >";
                      echo '</div>';
                      echo '<div>';
                         echo "<div>";
                              echo "<input id=txtCaptcha class=form-control type=text name=txtCaptcha value='' placeholder='Enter Verification Code' />";
                                   echo "<div><input class=btn btn-default type=button onclick=change_captcha() value=Reload /></div>";
                         echo "</div>";
                  echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";          //end of div
        echo "<span class =error id=errco>";        //this will show error of div
        if(isset($error))
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        echo '</span>';
        }
    ?>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="chq" value="">Remember Me</label>
 </div>

<div> 
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Login"class="btn btn-default" />
      <a href="signup.php" />Signup</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="forget_password.php" >Forgot Password</a>
  </div>

  <!--            <span id="span" ></span>                   span for showing output -->

              </form>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and yeah all work will must have in single form...not is two forms. here I used two forms but I want to have a single form

Comment: do some research on `ajax uploads`

Comment: alredy tried too much

Comment: Tried what? There are lots of tutorials and plugin scripts available. We don't know what problems you had implementing them

Answer (score 0):

GO through this liThis may Help You,
[Ajax upload image on form showing thumbnail](http://www.sitepoint.com/thumbnail-image-upload-ajaxphp/)